# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xml.sax' when I use add-apt-repository

Tags: command-line, apt, add-apt-repository

When I run this command in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leaeasy/dde
```

this problem appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 49, in <module>
    from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xml.sax'
```

What should I do?

**My Ubuntu Version is 17.10**

Comment: You should tell us which version of Ubuntu you use.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Python standard library package was corrupted. You can restore it with:

```
sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall libpython3.6-stdlib
```

Other packages on your system may be affected too. You can find them during a [sanity check](/a/57728/175814) and reinstall them in the same fashion as above.

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!